# PyQt wake main thread from non-QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, qthread

I have a PyQt application that receives information from an external source via callbacks that are called from threads that are not under my control and which are not `QThread`. What is the correct way to pass such information to the main thread, without polling? Particularly, I want to emit a Qt signal such that I can wake the main thread (or another `QThread`) upon arrival of new data.

Comment: Not sure to understand,can't  you change the source code of the non-qt thread ? like emit signal when finished ?

Comment: The only thing under my control is the callback function itself, which is a normal python function. I.e. I could emit signals, but would this be allowed? The thread which will run that function is not created by my code, and has no notion of Qt at all. So maybe I should ask if emitting signals is thread-safe (even from non Qt threads)?

Comment: I don't know if this is a best practice or a bad one, but that's how i would try to do, send a signal from your callback. I think it should work.  ( Qt Thread safety depend on the connection type : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads

Comment: The docs you are linking state "On the other hand, you can safely emit signals from your QThread::run() implementation, because signal emission is thread-safe." The second part says that your suggestion is fine, but the first part seems again to restrict this statement to QThreads...

Comment: Thread safety means that it should work even if it's not in a `QThread`-based thread.

Comment: Ok, thats great! If maybe one of you would summarise this again in a formal answer, then I could give you credit for it. A formal answer might also be useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default connection type for signals is [Qt.AutoConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), which the docs describe thus:

> If the signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving
>   object, the signal is queued, behaving as Qt::QueuedConnection.
>   Otherwise, the slot is invoked directly, behaving as
>   Qt::DirectConnection. The type of connection is determined when the
>   signal is emitted.

So before emitting a signal, Qt simply compares the **current** thread affinity of the sender and receiver before deciding whether to queue it or not. It does not matter *how* the underlying threads were originally started.

Here is a simple demo using a python worker thread:

```
import sys, time, threading
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self._callback = callback
        self._thread = None

    def active(self):
        return self._thread is not None and self._thread.is_alive()

    def start(self):
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self.work, name='Worker')
        self._thread.start()

    def work(self):
        print('work: [%s]' % threading.current_thread().name)
        for x in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
            self._callback(str(x))

class Window(QtGui.QPushButton):
    dataReceived = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__('Start')
        self.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.dataReceived.connect(self.receive)
        self.worker = Worker(self.callback)

    def receive(self, data):
        print('received: %s [%s]' % (data, threading.current_thread().name))

    def callback(self, data):
        print('callback: %s [%s]' % (data, threading.current_thread().name))
        self.dataReceived.emit(data)

    def start(self):
        if self.worker.active():
            print('still active...')
        else:
            print('start: [%s]' % threading.current_thread().name)
            self.worker.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    print('show: [%s]' % threading.current_thread().name)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Typical output:

```
$ python test.py
show: [MainThread]
start: [MainThread]
work: [Worker]
callback: 0 [Worker]
received: 0 [MainThread]
still active...
callback: 1 [Worker]
received: 1 [MainThread]
still active...
callback: 2 [Worker]
received: 2 [MainThread]
still active...
callback: 3 [Worker]
received: 3 [MainThread]
callback: 4 [Worker]
received: 4 [MainThread]
```

Comment: You say Qt "compared the current thread affinity of sender and receiver": How is thread affinity defined for the sender? Is it the actual thread (e.g. `threading.current_thread()`) or is it the thread the sending `QObject` lives in (which in your example is determined when `Worker` is created, which would be the wrong thread)? The former would make more sense and make your solution correct, while the latter conforms to the Qt doc's definition of "thread affinity":http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the sending object in your example is actually the same as the receiving object, it's `Window` (both the signal `dataReceived` and the slot `callback` are part of `Window`). Thus, if it would indeed use the "thread affinity" as per the docs, it would (wrongly) perform a direct call. I therefore conclude that Qt indeed compares the currently running thread (instead of the thread affinity of the sender) to the thread affinity of the receiver.

Comment: @burnpanck. Yes, "sender" means the worker in my example, because that is what actually invokes the callback function (which it has a reference to).

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it the same way I would if you were just polling an external device or library.  Create a separate worker thread that handles the callback, and emits an signal to the main GUI thread.

```
class Worker(QObject):

    data_ready = pyqtSignal(object, object)

    def callback(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data_ready.emit(args, kwargs)


class Window(...)

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.worker = Worker(self)
        # Connect worker callback function to your external library
        library.register_callback(self.worker.callback) #??
        ...

        # Mover worker to thread and connect signal
        self.thread = QThread(self)
        self.worker.data_ready.connect(self.handle_data)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.start()

    @pyqtSlot(object, object)
    def handle_data(self, args, kwargs):
        # do something with data
```

Comment: Is the thread `self.thread` really needed? What will it do? The function `Worker.callback` will of course still be executed on that unknown alien thread created by `library`...